# Query/Use Help Text from Object Fields in Aura?

Tags: apex, lightning, aura

Can I query and use the help text from object fields in an aura component?  I'm currently using lightning data service to get the record info into the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Helptext in apex using -

```
String helpText = SObject.FieldAPIName__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
```

replace sobject name and field api name with the object and field for which you need the help text.

Comment: Thank you!  Is it possible to retrieve this into an aura component using lightning data service, or do i have to use a controller to get the info?

Comment: @ShaunJones In lightning-record-edit-form (or lightning:recordEditForm in Aura) using lightning-input-field will display the helptext without any help from apex. If you are not using  lightning-record-edit-form then you will have to query the helptext in an AuraEnabled method.